# Replacement for DVL (Damn Vulnerable Linux)?

Tags: penetration-test, virtualization

I've recently spotted that DVL (Damn Vulnerable Linux) has gone inactive. My first question is what happened to cause them to stop releasing it?

Secondly, I have found some references to other testing environments, but was curious if there was an official/unofficial replacement for DVL that provides a large test bed for pentesting learning?

Comment: How horrible! DVL being inactive means that there will be no more security patches for it and all users will be damn vulnerable to... wait...

Comment: I highly recommend https://lab.pentestit.ru/; you connect virtual labs via vpn and proceed from bottom to top on your own.

Comment: Metasploitable is most likely the closest for what you are asking. It's only a VM though, which isn't great for certain needs.

Answer (score 11):

There are stacks: Metasploitable, DVWA, BWaPP, Mutillidae, WebGOAT (although the last few are vulnerable web apps).

There is also Hack.Me, a community project where people upload vulnerable sandboxes for others to practice against.

26/10/17 Edit to add: Vulnhub is a great resource for vulnerable & practice VMs. Meant to add this ages ago, apologies.

Troy Hunt has an online vulnerable web app to test against: http://hackyourselffirst.troyhunt.com

Alternatively, you could pay for access to Muts' student network (the gang that have released Kali - Offensive Security is the thing to search for.

There's loads of them around :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend http://vulnhub.com/ as a place to start looking, as they have been building a repository for pentesting VMs for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.codebashing.com/sql_demo .. they have created an interactive security war-game with integrated tutorials that walk you through a security vulnerability .. currently they support OWASP top 10 threats and are also working on a mobile security training portal.

Disclosure: I work for Codebashing as a developer

Answer (score 1):

There's a really good [list of resources](http://www.amanhardikar.com/mindmaps/Practice.html) which was created in 2016.

Just to pick out some vulnerable operating systems/builds:

- [Holynix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/holynix/files/)
- [Kioptrix](http://www.kioptrix.com/blog/)
- [LAMPSecurity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lampsecurity/)
- [Metasploitable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualhacking/files/os/metasploitable/)
- [neutronstar](http://neutronstar.org/goatselinux.html)
- [PenTest Laboratory](http://pentestlab.org/lab-in-a-box/)
- [Pentester Lab](https://www.pentesterlab.com/exercises)
- [pWnOS](http://www.pwnos.com/)
- [RebootUser Vulnix](http://www.rebootuser.com/?page_id=1041)
- [SecGame # 1: Sauron](http://sg6-labs.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/secgame-1-sauron.html)
- [scriptjunkie.us](http://www.scriptjunkie.us/2012/04/the-hacker-games/)